# How to evaluate dynamic values in URL by using regular expression?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have a route "/api/books/{id}/status" and I am wondering how can I evaluate a dynamic value ("{id}") by using regular expression, so I could restrict this route in my .htaccess file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure what you're up to. But to evaluate dynamic values in URL you have to use regular expressions. This has nothing to do with symfony. [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} api/books/[\d]+/status
```

If you want to restrict access to routes, you should use the [security component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security.html) of symfony.